# Getting iframe document in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to dynamically change the heigh of a iframe depending on it's contents.

However it's not working in the latest version of chrome.

doc is `'undefined'` in chrome.

It works fine in Firefox.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $('#iframeid')
                .load(
                        function() {

                            try {
                                var doc = this.contentDocument ? this.contentDocument
                                        : this.contentWindow.document;
                                alert(doc);
                            } catch (e) {
                                alert(e.message);
                            }
                        });

    });
</script>
<iframe frameborder="0" id="iframeid" src="iframesource2.html"
    height="1px"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work for me, though. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m8Ahy/).

Some little changes which should not really change anything:

```
$(function () {
    $('#iframeid').load(function () {
        try {
            var doc = this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document;
            alert(doc);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });
});
```